# Filter select from database using dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, filtering

I've got search page with 6 dropdownlists, 2 textboxes and a button in my asp.net web forms application. I need to select filtered data to a repeater component after clicking the button. I can do this when user select some values in all dropdownlists with SQL Select Command.

```
SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE (Sport = @Sport, Region = @Region, Name LIKE @Name,...)
```

But when user left some dropdownlist or textbox empty SQL Command doesn't display anything. Could anybody please help me, how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
I modified the query, but still it doesn't work.

```
SELECT Profiles.ProfileId,Profiles.ProPicUrl, Profiles.Name, Profiles.Specialization, UsersSports.Rating " + _
                             "FROM Profiles " + _
                                 "JOIN UsersSports ON Profiles.ProfileId = UsersSports.ProfileId " + _
                                "WHERE (UsersSports.SportId = CASE WHEN @SportId != '' THEN @Sport ELSE UsersSports.SportId END) AND (Region = CASE WHEN @Region != '' THEN @Region ELSE Region END) AND (Specialization = CASE WHEN @Specialization != '' THEN @Specialization ELSE Specialization END)" + _
                                        "AND (Sex = CASE WHEN @Sex != '' THEN @Sex ELSE Sex END) AND ((@AgeFrom IS NOT NULL AND @AgeTo IS NOT NULL AND Age BETWEEN @AgeFrom AND @AgeTo) OR (@AgeFrom IS NULL AND @AgeTo IS NULL AND Age)) " + _
                                        "AND ((@PractiseFrom IS NOT NULL AND @PractiseTo IS NOT NULL AND Practise BETWEEN @PractiseFrom AND @PractiseTo) OR (@PractiseFrom IS NULL AND @PractiseTo IS NULL AND Practise))" + _
                                        "AND ((@Name IS NOT NULL AND Name LIKE '%@Name%') OR (@Name IS NULL AND Name))  AND ((@City IS NOT NULL AND City LIKE '%@City%') OR (@City IS NULL AND City))" + _
                                "ORDER BY UsersSports.Rating ASC
```

Comment: Also `LIKE` should be used like `'%@Name%'` otherwise it works just like `=`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as follows - just ensure when a dropdown is not selected, the parameter is set to `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM Profiles 
WHERE (@Sport IS NULL OR Sport = @Sport)
    AND (@Region IS NULL OR Region = @Region)
    AND (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE (Sport = ISNULL(@Sport, Sport), Region = ISNULL(@Region, Region), Name LIKE ISNULL(@Name, Name),...
```

If "empty" is not NULL (but say empty string), then you have the option to use CASE, like this

```
SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE (Sport = CASE WHEN @Sport != '' THEN @Sport ELSE Sport END, ...
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use the `ISNULL()` function in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like following:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE";

if(ddlSports.SelectedIndex>0)
  query +=" Sports='"+ddlSports.SelectedValue+"' &";

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRegion.Text))
  query +=" Region='"+txtRegion.Text+"' &"
..
.. 
..
and so on

query = query.TrimEnd('&');
```

Comment: No need to use dynamic sql - this is possible in regular sql.